# Validation by using Json

Tags: visualforce, javascript, json

I have three rows on a Visualforce page. The requirement is that when any value of this field is blank it will show the error message on the page. I have to do this with the help of JSON and by using the following javascript function but I'm stuck. I am new on salesforce and JSON

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var text = '{"val":['{"TValueFields"}' ] }';
    obj = JSON.parse(text);

            function findBlank() {
            debugger;          
             for (i=0; i< obj.length; i++)
              {            
            var js = JSON.stringify(obj);
             if(document.getElementById(js).value == " ") 
             {           
              alert("TValueFields must be select");
              }
                    i++
       }
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use json, you can do it with by using javascript only ?

Comment: i have to pass this rows in json and call the javascript function. My Vf page is in Json

Comment: You will be more likely to get help here if you include the code that you have created so far. See [ask]

Comment: I've edited and added the code you put in an answer. Siddharth, can you say what the problem is with what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using some Table! which is having list of records, might be a wrapper list, and when you will hit some button and if the values in those fields are blank you need to show a validation message.

So you can do that using JavaScript function by traversing through DOM to find the element in particular row by doing something like this

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
```

or You can use Jquery Selectors to fetch values from table and perform validations based on that.

and if value of that element is blank show the alert message or highlight the input field.

However if you want to send some data to controller you can create a array to form Json as follow

```
 {
     "Id": SobjectId,
     "Name"         : SobjectName,
     "Phone"        : SobjectPhone        
 }
```

and using `JSON.stringify(YourArray)

you can send the data to controller by calling actionFunction on your CommandButton.

In controller side you can deserialize the Json string using JSON.deserialize and typeCast it to write datatype and you can do further manipulations.

Here is the code Snippet
1. Controller Class

```
public with sharing class WrapperListPageController {

//Variable Declaration
public List<AccountWrapper> accountWrapperList {get;set;}
public List<Account> accountList               {get;set;}

//Construtor
public WrapperListPageController(){
    if(accountWrapperList == null) {
        accountWrapperList = new List<AccountWrapper>();
        //For Now I am Limiting the accounts just for demo purpose, you need to do then pagination
        //for displaying more than 1000 accounts on VF page
        for(Account objAccount: [select Id, Name,BillingState, Website, Phone from Account limit 10]) {
            // As each Account is processed we create a new AccountWrapper object and add it to the accountWrapperList
            accountWrapperList.add(new AccountWrapper(objAccount));
        }//for
    }//if
}//WrapperListPageController

//Controller Action called onClick of Validate Table Values button.
public void validateTableValues(){
    system.debug('***Action Called***');
}//validateTableValues

//AccountWrapper
public class AccountWrapper {
    public Account objAccount {get;set;}
    public boolean isSelected {get;set;}

    public AccountWrapper(Account acc){
        objAccount = acc;
        isSelected = false;
    }//AccountWrapper
}//AccountWrapper
```

}//WrapperListPageController

2. Visualforce Page

   ```
               <apex:page controller="WrapperListPageController">

               <style>
                   .bPageBlock .detailList .dataCol {
                   width: 100%;
                   }

                   .border {
                       border-color: red; 
                       border-width: 1px; 
                       border-style: solid;
                   }
               </style>

               <apex:form >
                   <apex:pageBlock >

                       <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                           <apex:commandButton value="Validate Table Values" action="{!validateTableValues}" onclick="return validate()" rerender="table2"/>
                       </apex:pageBlockButtons>

                       <apex:pageblockSection title="Accounts Displayed" collapsible="false" columns="2">
                           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountWrapperList}" var="objAccWrapper" id="table" title="Accounts From Org">
                               <apex:column >
                                   <apex:facet name="header">
                                       <apex:inputCheckbox onclick=""/>
                                   </apex:facet>
                                   <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!objAccWrapper.isSelected}" id="inputId"/>
                               </apex:column>
                               <apex:column >
                                   <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
                                   <apex:inputField styleClass="accName-class" value="{!objAccWrapper.objAccount.Name}" />
                               </apex:column>
                               <apex:column >
                                   <apex:facet name="header">Billing State/Province</apex:facet>
                                   <apex:inputField styleClass="accBillSate-class" value="{!objAccWrapper.objAccount.BillingState}" />
                               </apex:column>
                               <apex:column >
                                   <apex:facet name="header">Phone</apex:facet>
                                   <apex:inputField styleClass="accPhone-class" value="{!objAccWrapper.objAccount.Phone}" />
                               </apex:column>
                           </apex:pageBlockTable>

                       </apex:pageblockSection>

                   </apex:pageBlock>

               </apex:form>


               <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

               <script>
                   var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
                   //Function to Validate Table Values
                   //I have added CSS to highlight, alternative you can add alert to display error message
                   function validate() {
                       var valid = true;
                       j$('input.accBillSate-class').each(function() {
                           if (j$(this).val() == '') {
                               j$(this).addClass('border');
                               valid = false;
                           }
                       });
                       return valid;
                   }//validate
               </script>
           </apex:page>
   ```
3. Final Result
   On Click of Validate Table Values Button Input Field gets highlighted. I still didn't understand why you need Json here, anyways I hope this will help you or let me know if you require something else.

You need to do modifiction to remove class for the condition when user put the values in textboxes which are required:

```
j$('.accPhone-class').each(function() {
            if (j$(this).val() === '') {
                j$(this).addClass('border');
                alert('****Please provide Account Phone');
                //valid = false;
            }
            else{
                j$(this).removeClass('border');
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Nachiket, This is the exact requirement which i want. can you provide me sample code?

Comment: anybody can help me?

Comment: Wait I will post the code shortly

Comment: Please check the answer if that satisfies your requirement, I am highlighting the blank input fields using red color that will give user a better Idea about which all fields are blank, you can perform the validation using same snippet for rest of the other fields.

Comment: You also need to do one change so that when user input the values in the required field it should remove that class
j$('.accPhone-class').each(function() {
                if (j$(this).val() === '') {
                    j$(this).addClass('border');
                    alert('****Please provide Account Phone');
                    //valid = false;
                }
                else{
                    j$(this).removeClass('border');
                }
            });